# creating a view of multiple tables using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, attribute-joins, table, sql-view

This might be the stupidest question for postgresql user. Please do understand that i just started to use postgresql.

what i am trying to do is joining 3 tables using same key field (which is polyong_id)

keyfield of table 1 = polygon_id, and it has additional fields that i want to keep
keyfield of table 2 = polygon_id, and it has venue_id field that i want to append
keyfield of table 3 = polyong_id, and it has feature_type field that i want to append

so what i did is

> ```
> Create View BULD as
> Select t1.shape, t1.polygon_id, t1.name, t1.height, t1.ground_clearance,
>        t1.iso_country_code, t2.venue_id, t3.feature_type, t3.main_feature_type
> From
>        BULD_base as t1, Venue as t2, Feature as t3
> Where
>        t1.polygon_id = t2.polygon_id and t1.polygon_id = t3.polygon_id
> ```

BULD's total number of records is about 60K and the result returned around 150 records.
I changed the AND to OR and it gave me same result.

I may create a view between t1 and t2, then 
and create another view between the table from the result above and t3 for the final result.

but I'd like to make a neat and smart query for this.

can anyone help?

Comment: actually if i create a view between t1 and t2, the result table view returned only 150 records... did it maybe leave records that only matches? hmmm... I want to keep all records though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way the query is written, it will return entries whose `polygon_id` exist in the 3 tables. If you want the entries that exist in the main table and eventually add the values from the 2nd and 3rd tables, you need to use a [left join](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/).

```
Create View BULD as
Select t1.shape, t1.polygon_id, t1.name, t1.height, t1.ground_clearance,
       t1.iso_country_code, t2.venue_id, t3.feature_type, t3.main_feature_type
From
    BULD_base as t1
    LEFT JOIN Venue as t2 ON t1.polygon_id = t2.polygon_id 
    LEFT JOIN Feature as t3 ON t1.polygon_id = t3.polygon_id;
```

Comment: OMG... you are my here

Comment: hmm.. i dont know why though it's missing 2 records somehow.
i will figure that out and leave a comment.
However, if you would know why, please also let me know